# Switching between activities rapidly spoils the Activity lifecycle. How to fix the issue?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I have 2 activities namely. ActivityA & ActivityB.

The structure of Activity A is:

```
public class ActivityA extends Activity
{
super.onCreate();
}

@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
}

@Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
}
```

Intent to goto ActivityB

```
private void GotoActivityB() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), B.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();   
}
```

The structure of ACTIVITY B is:

```
public class ActivityB extends Activity
{
super.onCreate();
}

@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
}

@Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
}
```

Intent to goto ActivityA

```
private void GotoActivityA() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), A.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();   
}
```

When I switch from Activity A to Activity B, the activity lifecycle goes through the following sequence:

onCreate(A); -> onStart(A); -> onStop(B);

Please note: I am not considering onPause and onResume here, as they are conventional to be called with onStop() and onStart() respectively.

When I switch from Activity A to Activity B, the activity lifecycle goes through the following sequence:

onCreate(B); -> onStart(B); -> onStop(A);

I am using icons to navigate through both activites by calling the mentioned intents.
Everything works well when I normally use the feature.

However, if I switch between these 2 activites very rapidly, in the following manner,

In Activity A, click "B" icon to goto Activity B, and immediately in Activity B, clicking "A" icon to goto Activity A.

This above operation spoils my activity lifecycle in the following way:

A to B

onCreate(A); -> onStart(A); -> onStop(B);

B to A

onCreate(B); -> onStop(A); -> onStart(B);

If you see here, onStop(A) is called before onStart(B), which defies the activity lifecycle.
This is very important for me as I am setting some boolean variables in the onStop and onStart and this spoilt lifecycle gives me wrong values and  crashes the application.

Comment: Explain how you're setting some boolean variables.

Answer (score 2):

I think the order of this callbacks in different activities is not defined and you should not rely on it.

The last `Activity` with called `onResume()` is the activity user interact with.
But there can be more than one activity that was started but not resumed.

Try to use `onResume()` and `onPause()` instead of `onStart()` and `onStop()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you no need to call the double side intent.

**firstActivity->use intent to start second one->secondActivity**

**secondActivity->backpressed->firstActivity**

you no need to maintain these states. why are you making yourself into trouble?
Easy Android. Cool.